# The nested menu number 4 which inside menu number three does't dropdown and show its items

Tags: drop-down-menu, dropdown

*The nested menu number 4 which inside menu number three does't dropdown and show its items*
I need to make nested menu ,I want the menu button number4 to be dropdown to show its items ,the menu button number 4 inside number 3 
,You can find the code here on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hassan_mousa97/pen/gOYxGeR)
I tried it and doesn't work with me

```css
#men {
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;

}

#men a {
  display: block;
  padding:0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
  line-height:auto;

}



label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
 padding : 17px 25px;;
  line-height: 1;
   color: #fff;
      background: #44494b!important;
 cursor :pointer;
border-radius: 8px;
}


input {
 display: none;
}

#men ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  background :#f4f4f4;
 list-style: none;

}


#men li {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}


#menu_bar01:checked ~ #links01 li,
#menu_bar02:checked ~ #links02 li, 
#menu_bar03:checked ~ #links03 li

{
  max-height: 46px;
  opacity: 1;

}
```

```html
<div class='button'>
 <div id='men'>

      <label for='menu_bar01' style='text-align: center'>number2</label>
    <input class='accordion' id='menu_bar01' type='checkbox'/>
     <ul id='links01'>
        <li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link01</a></li>
        <li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link02</a></li>
   
      </ul>

 <label for='menu_bar02' style='text-align: center'>number1  </label>
 <input class='accordion' id='menu_bar02' type='checkbox'/>

<ul id='links02'>
<li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link01</a></li>
<li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link02</a></li>
<li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link03</a></li>
<li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link04</a></li>
<li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link01</a></li>
<li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link02</a></li>
<li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link03</a></li>
<li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link04</a></li>
   </ul>
    <label for='menu_bar03' style='text-align: center'>number3</label>
    <input class='accordion' id='menu_bar03' type='checkbox'/>
    <ul id='links03'>
        <li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link01</a></li>
        <li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link02</a></li>
        <li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>

<label for='menu_bar04' style='text-align: center'>number4</label>
    <input class='accordion' id='menu_bar04' type='checkbox'/>
    <ul id='links04'>
        <li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link01</a></li>
        <li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link02</a></li>
        <li><a href='' style='text-align: center'>Link03</a></li>
 </ul>
</a></li>
   </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

hint: #men in css is the menu property

Answer (score 0):

i do it for you but it's in html and javascript.

this is the code:

html:

```
<div>
    <ul id="list">
      <li>
        <label onclick="handleClick(event)" id="number1">Number1</label>
        <ul id="number1-links" class="numbers deactive">
        <li class="links">Link01</li>
        <li class="links">Link02</li>
        <li class="links">Link03</li>
        </ul></li>
      <li>
        <label onclick="handleClick(event)" id="number2">Number2</label>
        <ul id="number2-links" class="deactive numbers">
          <li class="links">Link01</li>
          <li class="links">Link02</li>
          <li class="links">Link03</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label onclick="handleClick(event)" id="number3">Number3</label>
        <ul id="number3-links" class="numbers deactive">
          <li class="links">Link01</li>
          <li class="links">Link02</li>
          <li class="links">Link03</li>
          <li class="links">
            <label onclick="handleClick(event)" id="number4">Number4</label>
            <ul id="number4-links" class="deactive numbers">
              <li class="links">Link01</li>
              <li class="links">Link02</li>
              <li class="links">Link03</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and this is javascript:

```
handleClick = (event) => {
  let id = event.target.id
  let number1Links = document.getElementById(`${id}-links`)
  number1Links.classList.toggle("active")
  number1Links.classList.toggle("deactive")
}
```